# Correct use of hreflang / canonical tags on regional shopify stores

Tags: seo, shopify, canonicalization, regional-settings, hreflang

I'm setting up 2 regional shopify sites. Should I consider canonical tags or/and use hreflang to ensure that search engines will send my users towards the right site.

The first store covers the Europe region.
The second (and default) covers the remainder of the world.

Both stores are in English (UK), but their content will differ slightly (i.e they are not duplicate stores as such, and have different stock levels for example).

Currently Shopify includes the following tags:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url }}">
```

Which translates to:

EU Store:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.eu.example.me" />
```

Default Store:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.me" />
```

Should I alter this to use hreflang only? So the tags will be change to the following:

EU Store:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.example.me" />
```

Default Store:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-EU" href="http://www.eu.example.me" />
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO questions are off topic on here. Use https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LarryShatzer - noted.  Thanks.
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/119165/correct-use-of-hreflang-canonical-tags-on-regional-shopify-stores

Answer (score 1):

you can use those tags for any  country

for example , this tag is used for English (Australian)

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com/au/collection/dresses" hreflang="en-au" />
```

for example , this tag is used for English (United States)

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com/us/collection/dresses" hreflang="en-us" />
```

for example , this tag is used for English (United Kingdom)

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com/uk/collection/dresses" hreflang="en-gb" />
```

for example , this tag is used for Default

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com/au/collection/dresses" hreflang="x-default" />
```